# fatal error: types.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling

I'm attempting to compile Descent D1X for DOS, but whenever I run make I get

linuxnet.c:20:10: fatal error: types.h: No such file or directory
20 | #include "types.h"
|          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

I have libc6, libc6-dev, and their 1386 variants installed, and I cannot find how to point this thing towards the correct file.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.